# PHP MySQL Duplicate entry exception - InsertMulti with OnDuplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I am using ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class and I am trying to perform a multiple insert while using OnDuplicate. The goal is to insert a new product record if the 'sku' does not already exist. If the 'sku' does exist then the 'name' should be updated instead of creating a new entry.

**MySQL Schema:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`product_pk` bigint(9) NOT NULL,
`product_id` int(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`sku` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`category` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_update` timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `products`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_pk`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `sku` (`sku`);

ALTER TABLE `products`
MODIFY `product_pk` bigint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**PHP:**

```php
$sDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$lastid = $db->rawQuery('SELECT MAX( product_id ) AS max FROM products');
(!$lastid || !isset($lastid[0]['max'])) ? $pid = 0 : $pid = $lastid[0]['max']++;

foreach ($data as $item){
    if (isset($item['sku']) && !null == $item['sku']){
        $prod[$pid]['product_id'] = $pid;
        $prod[$pid]['sku'] = $item['sku'];
        $prod[$pid]['name'] = substr($item['product-name'],0,255);
        $prod[$pid]['last_update'] = $sDate;
        $pid++;
    }
}

$utfEncodedArray =encodeArray($prod, 'UTF-8');
$db->onDuplicate('name', 'product_pk');
$db->insertMulti('products', $utfEncodedArray);

function encodeArray($array, $type)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)){ $array[$key] = encodeArray($value, $type);}else{ $array[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($value, $type);}
    }
    return $array;
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry 'ABC123' for key 'sku'
```

Here is a sample of the array $utfEncodedArray used on the insertMulti call:

```
Array(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1
        [sku] => ABC123
        [name] => product1
        [last_update] => 2018-09-08 18:55:20
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2
        [sku] => ABC124
        [name] => product2
        [last_update] => 2018-09-08 18:55:20
    )
)
```

Steps I have tried so far:

- Dropped the 'products' table and created it again. Multiple times.
- Tried using 'sku' instead of 'product_pk' in the onDuplicate call.
- Tried multiple collation types
- Tried using unique key on both 'sku' and 'product_id'

  - When I attempted this method all entries were inserted correctly but when running it again it generated duplicates instead of updating the existing row. Not sure how this happened seeing as both 'sku' and 'product_id' are unique.

The $prod array currently contains the same values. So every time I run this I would expect to see the 'last_updated' column to be updated every time after the initial inserts.

This is my first experience using onDuplicate and despite hours of searching and reading docs I am still lost. I was trying to let the db class handle the multiple insert from the array but I am not against trying raw queries while iterating over my array of products instead.

Answer (score 0):

Of course as soon as I posted this I find the issue...

Found a fork of the database class which resolved issues with insertMulti while using onDuplicate:

[should fix insertMulti() if onDuplicate() is set](https://github.com/ricwein/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/commit/b6d23a6d4707f3d2be1cbe5a1485251f19c7b202)